# Class '\User' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am attempting to move all my User code in to it's own package for potential use on multiple projects, everything is working fine except for when I try to login and I get the following error:

```
Class '\User' not found
```

Now, I am assuming that this is because for some reason it is not finding the User model (I am using the default one that comes with Laravel but just moved to

`'Vendor/VendorName/PackageName/src/models'`

I can see that I can reference the User model from app/config/auth.php but if I change this to my package namespace I am seeing the same error but with the different path, also, I don't think that this is the best way to do this as for every project I will need to set the app/config/auth.php model which could prove to be pain, especially as I forget things!

Comment: Is there really a "\" at the start of the class name in the error message? That looks .. suspicious.

Comment: Yes there is, I'm pretty sure that this is standard as the config/auth.php file is just 'User' so it looks as though Laravel is adding in the /

Comment: That means it's looking for `User` in the global namespace. You will need to add the appropriate `use` statement

Comment: As I mentioned the /is being added by Laravel I think. Where should I put this use statement? I have tried it in my UserController but this doesn't work.

Comment: if you moved it to 'Vendor/VendorName/PackageName/src/' you have to make sure composer registered it for autoloading, show your composer file

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have not autoloaded User. Below is an example of how Laravel do use autoload in composer, the User class is at installation placed inside "app/models", which is autoloaded there. If you have moved your User anywhere else you need to autoload it from there.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models", // original path for User.php
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "your/new/path" // here you add your new path that should autoload
    ]
}
```

And do not forget to run `composer dump-autoload` after updating your composer.json file!

Comment: sorry but this doesn't seem to work either, here is my composer.json line: "vendor/seriousjelly/user/src/models/User.php", I have also tried just using the path to the models folder. I still get the same issue :(

Comment: add a new `vendor/...` path solved my issue, just curious whether this is best practices since all libraries are included within the `app` folder here

Comment: @TheRabbitFactory sorry for very late answer, must have missed out on your comment. Anyhow, have you made sure to run composer dumpautoload after updating your composer.json?

Comment: @ulkas Well, best practice is hard to say without looking at your code. But just make sure you are only loading the necessary files and not your entire vendor directory.